# How to force chromium build for webrtc to use GCC instead of clang for compilation

Tags: c++, windows, webrtc, chromium

As per chromium docs, chromium build system uses clang for compilation on windows machine. But I need webrtc native library compiled from minGW gcc only. So is there any way to change default compiler from clang to minGW gcc ?

I googled for same, and found that it can be done via changing CC in build.ninja file. But I couldn't find this specific setting in build.ninja.

Thanks,
Shashi